# Apache 2.4 Cache with VirtualHost Proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, caching, proxy, virtualhost

I want to activate caching on Apache 2.4 for a website on Tomcat     passing through Apache with a VirtualHost configuration.

This is my apache2.config file code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com

  #Cache
  CacheEnable disk /
  CacheHeader on
  CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
  CacheDefaultExpire 800
  CacheMaxExpire 64000
  ExpiresActive on

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8084/Application/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8084/Application/

</VirtualHost>
```

The Caching works in my local machine (Ubuntu), but not on the production server (Ubuntu Server).

Basically I check the cache directory with

ls -la /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk/

and in my local machine I get lots of cached files with the correct date, but on my server the directory remains empty.

Any ideas, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. Basically I did not enable the "cache_disk". I don't understand why apache restarts without giving me an error. That's why I did't think about it. Anyways the solution was

sudo a2enmod cache_disk

Answer (score 1):

1. Is caching module enabled ? If so, you'll see those directives names you are using with

`httpd -L | grep -i cache`

2. Are the permissions correctly set for your cache directory ?

`ls -lZ yourdir # check selinux 
getfacl yourdir # check for the account running the process`

3. Are these resources authorized to be cache ? Run a `curl` command and look for the caching headers (`pragma`, `cache-control`)

Comment: 1. I run "apachectl -L | grep -i cache" and go the same in both local and server.

Comment: 2. getfacl /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk is also the same (owner: www-data group: www-data, user::rwx group::r-w other::r-w).

Comment: 3. I am not using pragma (I think its deprecated), but I use Cache-Control and I get Response Header "Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400" on both local and server. But still no cached files in the server at /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk. Any chance its being cached in another directory and I don't know it?

Comment: If it is served from the cache, you should see ETag and Age headers in the response. Are these headers present ?

Comment: Thanks Eugene, as I wrote, I have already found the problem. I do have an "Age" header, but there is no "Etag" header.

Comment: sorry, I didn't know I had to mark my own answer. thanks